# Getting token and contract information using Nethereum

Tags: smartcontracts, nethereum

I am looking at this staking contract (pancake swap):

> 0x73feaa1ee314f8c655e354234017be2193c9e24e

and it's token (cake):

> 0x0e09fabb73bd3ade0a17ecc321fd13a19e81ce82

you can find a summary here:

https://bscscan.com/token/0x0e09fabb73bd3ade0a17ecc321fd13a19e81ce82?a=0x73feaa1ee314f8c655e354234017be2193c9e24e

On bscscan, I can get the following information:

- price of token $12.54
- market cap $2.9b
- supply 231m
- holders 137k
- balance 88m (cake)

With nethereum, when I call:

```
web3.Eth.GetBalance.SendRequestAsync
```

I get:

- with staking contract address: 479430015101300880
- with token address: 3459819507903896496

and I'm not sure what the units are, nor how to map this to the information from bscscan.

I'm trying to get both the token value, but also what is the balance in the contract and I can't seem to find a way to do this.

so I looked at the nethereum playground and found an example dealing with ERC20 tokens, but when I put my addresses in it, the output is 0 and absolutely no error message, etc.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere? I'm currently finding this whole learning curve very steep and annoying. I think I'm getting somewhere then I end up reading a load more documentation and never actually answer my first questions

Comment: @ChrisLomax, yes, I ended up figuring out most of the info I needed; it takes quite a while but it's very simple in the end. Do you have something specific you're trying to extract?